# Does this code result in infinite allocation at run time?

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct trie_node
{
    trie_node() : is_leaf{true}, children(26), c{' '} {};
    bool is_leaf{false};
    std::vector<trie_node> children;
    char c{' '};
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    trie_node t;
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, it compiles correctly. However, when examining the code, it appears that there's an infinite loop going with the allocation since the member variable `children` is a vector of `trie_node`. So when `t` is created, it would create a vector of of size 26 of `trie_node` objects, and each of these 26 elements would in turn create another vector of size 26 of `trie_node` objects and so on. Is my understanding correct? If so, why does the compiler not give a warning or error for this?

Comment: *Is my understanding correct?* Yes.  *If so, why does the compiler not give a warning or error for this?* Look up the halting problem.

Comment: @David "_why does the compiler not give a warning or error for this?_" 1) Probably, because it isn't mandated by C++ stadard. 2) How would compiler detect it, in general case?

Comment: compilers are not made to detect logic errors in your code

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah I see. What if I changed `std::vector<trie_node> children` to `trie_node *children[26]`? In this case, it would seem to avoid the issue?

Comment: Better to change `std::vector<trie_node> children` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<trie_node>> children`

Comment: You can cause the same problem in most other languages - C#, Java, Perl, Python etc.

Comment: You can also solve the problem by 1. Avoiding to fix the size of the vector to 26 when creating the struct 2. Setting the size to 26 only when you will have to effectively use this vector

Comment: @Damien I saw the following definition in a section of class notes. To me, it seems like it results in the same problem infinite loop allocation problem unless you have a default constructor that sets all elements of children to `nullptr`? 

```class TrieNode {
public:
    TrieNode *children[26];
};```

Comment: @David With a pointer to an array, you don't call the initialisation of all elements of the array. It will happen only when calling `new`. Then, no infinite loop allocation.

Comment: @Damien Ah yes. My C++ is a bit rusty, but now I remember.

Comment: @Damien Also, you stated pointer to "an array." But here, isn't it just an array of pointers.

Comment: @David Maybe effectively. it is a  long time I have not used such a construction. I prefer to use `vector` now. But it doesn't change the fact that initialisation is not performed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your understanding is correct.

> why does the compiler not give a warning or error for this?

Your code is syntactically correct C++ code so an error is out of the question.

To give a warning on this a compiler would have to detect the problem. Since the allocation is buried in a few abstraction layers it is very difficult to design and implement an algorithm that can reliably detect this scenario. Also it's not worth it since it would 1. be a very rare scenario 2. be immediately detected at runtime anyway.